# I need associate tables in sequelize + typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I need associate tables with sequelezie + typescript, but i receive this error: **Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'sales_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'veicles'**, i'm leaving the repository link for easier understanding.

https://github.com/paulozy/auto-luby

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import { db } from '../database'
import { UserModel } from './UserModel'
import { VeicleModel } from './VeicleModel'

interface ISaleModel extends Model {
  saleID: number
  userID: number
  veicleID: number
  saleValue: number
  veicleStatus: 'SOLD' | 'AVAILABLE' | 'RESERVED'
  createdAt: Date
}

export const SaleModel = db.define<ISaleModel>('sale', {
  saleID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  priceSold: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    allowNull: false
  },
  soldAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false
  }
})
SaleModel.belongsTo(VeicleModel, { foreignKey: 'veicleID' })
SaleModel.belongsTo(UserModel, { foreignKey: 'userID' })

import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize"
import { db } from "../database"
import { SaleModel } from "./SaleModel"
import { ReserveModel } from "./ReserveModel"

interface IVeicleModel extends Model {
  VeicleID: number
  brand: string
  model: string
  yearFabrication: number
  kmRotate: number
  chassi: string
  color: string
  status: 'SOLD' | 'AVAILABLE' | 'RESERVED'
}

export const VeicleModel = db.define<IVeicleModel>('veicle', {
  veicleID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  brand: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
    allowNull: false
  },
  model: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
    allowNull: false
  },
  yearFabrication: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  kmRotate: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    allowNull: false
  },
  chassi: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    allowNull: false
  },
  color: DataTypes.STRING(10),
  status: DataTypes.STRING(20),
  price: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
  createdAt: DataTypes.DATE
})
VeicleModel.hasMany(SaleModel)
VeicleModel.hasMany(ReserveModel)
```

HELP-ME PLEASE

Comment: Can you explain at what context do you get the error? when? It will be easier to investigate.

Comment: It seems a default `id` field is missing for all models. You need to define `id` field for VeicleModel which will be associated with the foreign key `veicleID`.

Comment: @hotcakedev i have this field in VeicleModel and yout migration, i need add this field in SaleModel also?

Comment: @dina i have four tables, users, veicles, sales and reserves. The tables sales and reserves receive a foreignKey(veicleID and userID) of others tables, but when i run the migrations i receive this error

Comment: @paulo-abreu It would be better if you add id for each table.

Comment: @hotcakedev i made it, but i yet receive the same error. I think that code is wrong for associate this tables. And I don't find content about sequelize associate + typescript ;-;

Comment: I see only two migration scripts on the repo shared and the migration just runs fine with those two tables.

Comment: @dina sorry, I didn't have commited the update's, now is update.

Answer (score 0):

abreu,

I tried out your repo locally. Here's my branch. I assume you are using MySQL as your application database. I've added that locally using a docker-compose file and tested your repo locally. It seems to work fine for me. I will share some screenshots here.

[image]

[image]

I added a PR if you'd like to test it out in the docker environment.